# Why am I getting an error while using 'data.loc' for a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I am working on a dataset by WHO on Google Collab.

For some columns, 'data.loc' is working completely. For example:

1. `data.loc[(data['Country'] == 'Bangladesh'), ['Country', 'Year', 'infant deaths']]`
2. `data.loc[(data['Country'] == 'Bangladesh'), ['Country', 'Year','Adult Mortality']]`

However, there is a column called 'Life expectancy'. I have checked multiple times whether I mistyped or not. But every time I want to see columns having a 'Life expectancy' value for Bangladesh, I get an error message/response.

Code used:

3. `data.loc[(data['Country'] == 'Bangladesh'), ['Life expectancy']]`

Error Image:

[image]

My First 5 columns for better visualization of my dataset:

[image]

Comment: Please do not include images of errors or dataframes. Include them as copyable text in the question.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any spaces in the column name? Use print(data.columns) to check the names. Maybe you'll notice something what is suspicious.

Comment: `r = re.compile("\s*Life expectancy\s*")` then
`print(list(filter(r.match, df.columns.to_list())))`. It will make it easier to see what the spacing is.

Comment: @Arkadiusz Finally, it worked.